# Mongodb - Convert standalone server to replica set in the config file

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to convert a standalone mongodb instance to a replica set so that I can setup a river with elasticsearch. The directions for how to start one from the command line seem straight forward, however, I want it to automatically boot as a replica set upon server reboot. I currently have mongodb starting via a config file setup. I'm confused about how do I setup the config to work for a standalone replica set. Also, do I have to set it up first using the directions at http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/convert-standalone-to-replica-set/, or will the config file boot handle this.

The part of the config file that I am confused with is:

```
# Replication Options

# in master/slave replicated mongo databases, specify here whether
# this is a slave or master
#slave = true
#source = master.example.com
# Slave only: specify a single database to replicate
#only = master.example.com
# or
master = true
#source = slave.example.com

# in replica set configuration, specify the name of the replica set
#replSet = rs0
```

Let's assume that my server is located at 123.456.789.000 and the name for the replica set is rs0.

Comment: 1. stackexchange is a community for software developers, not for database administrators. But we also have one for database administrators. It can be found on https://dba.stackexchange.com. I nominated your question for migration. 2. `123.456.789.000` is not a valid IP address :)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I'll use that one for future questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need `replSet` set in your config file, assuming MongoDB is already configured to use that config file and start at boot you should be good. The `rs.initiate()` step is a one-time step that needs to be run.